# Как прижать ссылку к низу блока и выровнять по центру?

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrap_product {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f6d28e;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

.more_button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_product">
  <a href="{{ $latest_solution->link }}" class="more_button">
    <span>more</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Вот так прижалась но отцентрировать не могу.

Если убрать `position: absolute;` тогда станет по центру но ссылка не будет прижиматься к низу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.wrap_product {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f6d28e;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

.more_button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Дополнил строки ниже*/
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_product">
  <a href="{{ $latest_solution->link }}" class="more_button">
    <span>more</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @wantstudy, всегда пожалуйста...